# Geoserver - tiles/grid offset

Tags: geoserver

I would like to host an Openstreetmap server using Geoserver (Geoserver/GeoWebCache/postgis). However, I encounter a problem regarding the tiles and gridsets. TMS urls (myserv/z/x/y.png) are different than urls from openstreetmap.org or MapQuest. Furthermore, there is an offset on the y axis.
The following url shows an area from my own server. The other url shows the same area from Mapquest.

[http://devmobicite.dnsroute.fr:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/mapServer:mapOSM/14/16280/12392.png](http://devmobicite.dnsroute.fr:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/mapServer%3amapOSM/14/16280/12392.png)

http://mtile01.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/vy/map/15/16280/11637.png

The offset seems to be caused by the zoom level (here 14~=15) and by the y value (12392->11637). 
I hope my issue is understandable and that someone can help me.

(Sorry for my english)

Thanks

Raphaël

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic difference between TMS and Google/Openstreetmap Tiles is that TMS counts from bottom left, and the others from top left:

http://alastaira.wordpress.com/2011/07/06/converting-tms-tile-coordinates-to-googlebingosm-tile-coordinates/

Maybe WMTS is the service you want.

Comment: Yes, I had this information. I saw that the way to get the "translated" y value is y = (2^zoom - 1) - y and I tried to use without great results. That's why I think my problem comes from the zoom offset.

Comment: Ok, now i see the offset to the north. might be because the upper bound is rounded to 85.0511°, which is not exactly arctan(sinh(π)): http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames. But I don't know how to solve that in Geoserver.

Comment: Actually WMTS works well for me. I used it with a bad EPSG during my test. Now it's perfect. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you specify "good" and "bad" EPSG for future users?

Comment: Yes. I used the EPSG:4326 gridset instead of the EPSG:900913 one. They are the default ESPG gridsets proposed by geoserver.